# Script in repo requires different shell-script headers for different computers

Tags: git, shell, nixos

I use `nixos` and my bash path is `/run/current-system/sw/bin/bash`, therefore I require a shell-script header of

```
#!/run/current-system/sw/bin/bash
```

My colleagues use macOS and they require the more standard shell-script header of

```
#!/bin/bash
```

There are some scripts in our git repository which I alter in order to run our repo on my machine. I currently deal with this via profuse use of `git stash`. What is a better way?

There may be some git feature for somehow toggling these changes, setting the repo for use on my machine, and I would be interested to hear about that. Also would be interested to hear how I might edit the script to work unaltered on both types of machine.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` ? That should be portable between NixOS / macOS / other systems.

Comment: @ppb Requires `/run/current-system/sw/bin/` to be in PATH but otherwise very good solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this by using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env command
```

But you need to be aware that the main disadvantage of using this approach is that it will call the first `<command>` that your `$PATH` returns.

For example, if using

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

It could return either python2 or python3, depending on what your `$PATH` returns first.

Comment: You can use nix-shell to specify precisely which interpreter to use: https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#use-as-a-interpreter (assuming nix is installed)